# Jasperreports field with dynamic value from xml node

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports

I have some jrxml template with xml datasource and I have `myField` visible below, however I need to refactor it to make it conditional because new xml formats are introduced and car owner is not always in the same place (`/owner/name` vs `ownerName`):

```
<field name="myField" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression"  value="string(./car/owner/name)"/>
    </field>
```

and this field should be created somehow to take /owner/name OR ownerName, depending on what is available. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is to have a XPath that can handle both `./car/owner/name` and `./car/ownerName`, you could use:

```
string(./car/owner/name|./car/ownerName)
```

Depending on if you can use XPath 2.0 you could also use:

```
string(./car/(owner/name|ownerName))
```